# Android 11 IjkMediaPlayer and GiraffePlayer2 issue

Tags: android, ijkplayer

I am using GiraffePlayer2 which is using IjkMediaPlayer for implementation. I am getting crash on Android 11 and above versions while using lazyLoad library. Here is the logcat:-

```java
2021-08-05 11:47:02.253 2872-2959/daily.status.earn.money E/atus.earn.mone: No implementation found for void tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.native_finalize() (tried Java_tv_danmaku_ijk_media_player_IjkMediaPlayer_native_1finalize and Java_tv_danmaku_ijk_media_player_IjkMediaPlayer_native_1finalize__)
2021-08-05 11:47:02.253 2872-2959/daily.status.earn.money E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2021-08-05 11:47:02.254 2872-2959/daily.status.earn.money E/System: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.native_finalize() (tried Java_tv_danmaku_ijk_media_player_IjkMediaPlayer_native_1finalize and Java_tv_danmaku_ijk_media_player_IjkMediaPlayer_native_1finalize__)
        at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.native_finalize(Native Method)
        at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.finalize(IjkMediaPlayer.java:958)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

and other logcat:-

```java
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x77b4b6ec08 in tid 29207 (ff_read), pid 28875 (atus.earn.money)
```

I am using Proguard configuration as mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/tcking/GiraffePlayer2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with this:
https://source.android.google.cn/devices/tech/debug/tagged-pointers

Add this to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
  <application android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false">
  ...
  </application>
```